# unterminated string literal when adding image to span

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

i want to add image inside a span
here's what i tried (**inside a form** i added this script):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
       function addSelected(){
             var content=" <img src='/resources/images/image.bmp'/> ";
             var span = document.getElementById("members"); 
             span.innerHTML=content;
              }
          </script>
```

but it always gives me the error:

**unterminated string literal**

on this line:

```
var content=" <img src='/resources/images/image.bmp'/> ";
```

because it's translated by browser to something like (found that by firebug):

```
var content=" <img src="/resources/images/CONTACTS.bmp" /> &#34;;
```

this is tested on firefox 8.

Comment: "It's translated" – translated by what?

Comment: Please post the HTML markup this is modifying. Something is probably incorrect there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about this:

```
var content = document.createElement("img");
content.src = "/resources/images/image.bmp";
span.appendChild(content);
```

This the standard way of adding elements to the DOM using DOM itself. And you avoid these kind of problems.

Comment: when i tried that, nothing is added to span ! but i get no errors in console !

Comment: my bad, i had to add application context before the url, it works very fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the object exists before you call span?  What he posted should work.

Comment: @sameh frahat Nice, it's better to do this way as you're using common standards, which may mean you've a more "cross-browser code" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `\` before any `"` in the `content` string.

```
var content=" <img src=\"/resources/images/image.bmp\"/> ";
```

Comment: when i try that i get the error: `Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "src". `

Comment: Are you sure that you are doing it exactly like he did?  Note that he isn't escaping the 1st and last double quotes.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code in the question or the code in this answer; I think there must be something else going on here...

Comment: This is a simple js string, escaping quotes is really basic stuff.. Here we got a double-quoted string (between `"`) and we escape every `"` inside it with `\\`.

Comment: i have no idea why it's not working, i am putting the JS function inside a form (and i am making JSF application), maybe this will help.